# Conditional fields on block add form

Tags: blocks

I have a custom block type created through the UI and I used the configuration files to export it to a module.
My custom block type has two fields and I want users to be able to fill out one or the other, but not both.

Is there way to implement that logic through the UI?
If not, how can I create the custom block type in code and add this logic?

Comment: [Drupal webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) will give you the logic you need

Answer (score 0):

i just found this module that is supposed to do that

https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

I believe a form alter function on a module should do the trick however i haven't implemented anything like it.

Good luck.